Spring boot sftp sshd-sshclient - Initiating key re-exchange log every one minute after 30 min of idle state
I am using spring boot integration to pull the files from sftp server and if server is idle for 30 min after that I see the log every one minute
[sshd-SshClient[4e4538bb]-timer-thread-1] INFO  o.a.s.c.s.ClientSessionImpl - requestNewKeysExchange(ClientSessionImpl[server]) Initiating key re-exchange
This is not stopping application from processing another files but this is logging continously, what we can do to stop this
